# Atlassian's Confluence and Maven's POM config

Tags: java, pom.xml, confluence

I have to write a plug-in for **Atlassian Confluence** by using Atlassian SDK and and Java's SDK v8 on Eclipse IDE. Apache Maven (3.2.1) comes with Atlassian SDK which I have to use it from there (because there are a couple of dependencies that are shipped with the sdk that are not available in a maven repository); so I set the environment variables to point in there. Although, the POM file that I have to use comes with errors.
For example:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version> <!-- 2.2.2 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
        <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
        <version>${confluence.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

On both dependencies it says, **missing artifact**, e.g.,

```
Missing artifact com.atlassian.confluence:confluence:jar:5.8.10
```

Although, in both cases, for example:

```
com.google.code.gson
```

the jar file at m2 actualy exists, yet the error at the POM file notifies that the artifact is missing.

I tried the **atlas-mvn clean package**, even after wiping the m2 repository explicitelly, and rerunning that command though it did not resolve the problems.
Did any body come across such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to take each the *.repositories file under specific artifact dir (which causes problems), and perform following modifications, for example:

```
maven-confluence-plugin-6.2.2.jar>atlassian-public=
```

Needs to appear in the following format:

```
maven-confluence-plugin-6.2.2.jar>=
```

And it's done!